# windows 10 iot raspberry pi 3 wifi hotspot

Tags: powershell, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core, hotspot

I am trying to make my RPi 3 an AP using Windows 10 IoT core. RPi is connected with internet through Ethernet port and I want to make RPi 3 builtin WiFi to share internet with other devices. I have read [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/deviceportal) page but it is not working for me. I have tried with Windows IoT Onboarding and from [PowerShell](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c65ee123-6f0e-4d88-bdba-c43dec530f0f/iot-core-on-rpi-wifi-as-access-point?forum=WindowsIoT) also. After selecting adapters from IoR Onboarding, clicked on start sharing service and a message appears which says "internet conncetion sharing has started" but I can't find network on other devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After selecting adapters from IoR Onboarding, clicked on start sharing
>   service and a message appears which says "internet conncetion sharing
>   has started" but I can't find network on other devices.

You could open Windows Device Portal and set your raspberry pi3 as the [following instruction](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/deviceportal). Before doing this you would connect your raspberry pi3 with WLAN.

1. Select IoT Onboarding option on the left of the page. Then an Adapter configuration must be chosen. You could choose Access point adapter Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter #2 and choose Shared network adapter LAN9512/LAN9514 USB 2.0 to Ethernet 10/100 Adapter.
   [image]
2. Then clicked on start sharing service. You could see the message appears which says "internet conncetion sharing has started".
   [image]
3. At last make sure select enable in radio box and click on save button under the SoftAP settings. There is a message says reboot your raspberry pi3 for changes to take effect the SoftAP settings. Please click yes and your raspberry pi3 will be restarted.
   [image]
4. After your raspberry pi3 is started you could connect your devices like PC or mobile phone on the SoftAP which is on raspberry pi3.
   [image]